# How to append react component on click

Tags: reactjs

I created a component in react and I'm trying to make a function that appends that component every time I click on a button this is an example of what I want to do

I'm sorry if the question looks stupid I'm still a student

```
import { Component } from "react";
import {DragDropContext ,Droppable,Draggable} from "react-beautiful-dnd"
import Test from "./Test"; //this the component that i want to append
class Home extends Component{


    render(){
  let AddComponent = function(){
      let parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
      parent.appendChild(<Test index={0} id={"0"} content="test1"/>)

  }
 
        return(
            
            <div className="container">
                
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
    <Droppable droppableId="uniqe" className="parent" >
    {(provided) => (
        <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>


{AddComponent()}

<button onClick={AddComponent}>Add Component</button>
{provided.placeholder}
</div>
)}

</Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
</div>

    


  



   
        )
    }
}
export default Home
```

i was expecting to append component on click but I got an error

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature react portal. https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `AddComponent` with DOM manipulation is outside of [React's life-cycle and state management](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) which is an anti-pattern that we should avoid.

Ideally, we should handle all DOM changes with React's states.

For the sake of your requirement, you can use `setState` to listen to state changes in React that will make your UI re-rendering with latest data

```
import { Component } from "react";
import {DragDropContext ,Droppable,Draggable} from "react-beautiful-dnd"
import Test from "./Test"; //this the component that i want to append
class Home extends Component{
    constructor() {
       this.state = { addedComponentCount: 0 }
    }

    //add your testing component with the count increment
    addComponent = () => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ addedComponentCount: prevState.addedComponentCount + 1 }))
    }
    render(){
        return(<div className="container">         
                <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
                    <Droppable droppableId="uniqe" className="parent" >
                        {(provided) => (
                            <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                                {(new Array(this.state.addedComponentCount)).map((value, index) => <Test key={index} id={index}>)}
                                <button onClick={this.addComponent}>Add Component</button>
                            {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                        )}
                    </Droppable>
                </DragDropContext>
                </div>)
    }
}
```